# how to add a custom module in google colab?

Tags: object, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, google-colaboratory

I want to run training on data, but it doesn't run properly and shows me a module error:

```
"File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'"
```

As far as I understand, custom modules inside the object detection folder cannot be run because of this error. This happened before. I fixed it somehow, but I don't remember how. Now I've tried to add pythonpath or change working directory, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me how to fix this again?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the tensorflow models(only if you haven't already)

```
%%bash
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

Then, run the following commands from the /tensorflow/models/research directory:

```
!python setup.py build   #builds the tensorflow models (this might take a while)
!python setup.py install #Install the models 
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. #protobuf compilation
cd slim
!pip install -e . #install slim
cd .. #back to research direcotry
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim  #set the path
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py #Test the object detection model(optional)
```

If everything goes fine, you would see the following output

Ran 22 tests in 0.152s

OK (skipped=1)

Then you must be able to run your training script without this error.

Note: just in case, if you come across error related to protobuf compiler, get the version 3.0.0 into the "tensorflow/models/research" directory and then follow the above mentioned steps.

```
wget -O protobuf.zip https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip protobuf.zip
```